# Android Push notification Status Icon issue

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I am facing issue while using push notification Firebase,
Issue : 
App Icon appears white on a marshmallow and above, so I created the white and transparent set of icons, now push notification icons to appear as I needed **but** only when the app is on the **foreground** when a user gets a notification and **app is closed** the icon appears white itself.

**My Manifest**

```
<application
        android:name="com.xxxx"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_xxxx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**Notification Code : when I get push notification**

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.xxxxxx)
                        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent))
                        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            } else {
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            }



            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build());
```

**on Message Recieve Code**

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message TITLE: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message BODY: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message DATA: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        //remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getData());
    }
```

Comment: Ok can you post your `onMessageReceived` code?

Comment: Have you tried to add the icon using the platform on your drawable folder (drawable/drawable-v21)? 
This is a cleaner way to solve this issue which won't relay on runtime checks.

Comment: @GhostDerfel : nope , I added the icons in the other folder namely drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi ......

Comment: @GhostDerfel : No Progress ,I Tried to add icons on drawable/drawable-v21 but no sucess, however when I change my application icon  (in Manifest ) to transparent and white one the background push sows that ,but it is not i want , I need my app icon to be colour full

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of notification there.

1.) using default params

```
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
```

Server Side Code:

```
{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

This type of implementation only works when the app is open or in background. You will notified message received ( blank notification will appear as you said) but you won't get any data from it.

2.) using map

```
   Map data =  remoteMessage.getData();
```

Server Side Code:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}
```

This will receive even after the app closed. It won't produce the blank white notification.

Comment: yes , I know that ,check my on message receive code

Comment: okay, As I said your message received code is won't work when the application closed. how can you use title, body and also data? you can only use either one method.

Comment: I have the same code as you do and I am using remoteMessage.getData() inside the method, The remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() is not used in an actual method, please avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

IF its issue with notification icon as white. Try adding this code in manifest

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" 
android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />
```